# BCC shipment email only when "Send shipment email" is checked

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

I need to **BCC** the shipment email to an email-address whenever I send the email to the customer.

I have added the **BCC** address in

> Backend - System - Configuration - Sales section - Sales Emails tab

however this does also **BCC** the shipping email when not sent to the customer.

*I send it to the postal service first for processing, and later to the customer when Magento has received the tracking information.*

I therefore need to add **BCC** to the template instead.

Anyone know where and how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct behavior, the *Magento* always sends **BCC** email even if it should not to be send to customer.

To avoid it you need rewrite the `sendEmail` method of the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment` class in your custom extension or override this class via the following directory:

> Magento_root/app/code/local/Mage

and you need replace the following line of code in the `sendEmail` method:

```
if (!$notifyCustomer && !$copyTo) {
    return $this;
}
```

by the following line of code:

```
if (!$notifyCustomer) {
    return $this;
}
```